# DNS with OpenVPN on a linux server with routing enabled

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu, dns, openvpn

I am running a `Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS` headless server. Before I enabled routing, my [AirPort Extreme](https://www.apple.com/airport-extreme/) was the router. At that point, DNS was not an issue. Ever since I stopped using the AirPort Extreme, and the `Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS` headless server became the router, DNS has not worked when OpenVPN is connected. So just to reiterate, the problem is that `ping 173.194.219.139` works, but `ping google.com` does not work.

Here are the relevant configuration files:

```
/etc/network/interfaces

# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# Bridge setup
auto br0 em1
iface br0 inet dhcp
bridge_ports em1

auto br1 em2 veth0
iface br1 inet static
address 10.0.0.1
network 10.0.0.0
netmask 255.255.255.0
broadcast 10.0.0.255
bridge_ports em2 veth0

# pre and post up
pre-up ip link add name veth0 type veth peer name veth1
pre-up ip netns add vpn
pre-up ip link set veth1 netns vpn
post-up ip netns exec vpn ip link set dev lo up
post-up ip netns exec vpn ip link set dev veth1 up
post-up ip netns exec vpn ip addr add 10.0.0.254/24 broadcast 10.0.0.255 dev veth1
post-up ip netns exec vpn ip route add default via 10.0.0.1


iptables

*nat
-A POSTROUTING -o "$EXTIF" -j MASQUERADE
COMMIT
*filter
:INPUT DROP [0:0]
:FORWARD DROP [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]

# ALLOW COMMUNICATION WITH NETNS VPN
-A FORWARD -o "$INTIF" -j ACCEPT
# ALLOW STATES RELATED,ESTABLISHED
-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
# LOOPBACK
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
# ICMP
-A INPUT -i "$INTIF" -p icmp -j ACCEPT
# DNS
-A INPUT -i "$INTIF" -p tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i "$INTIF" -p udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
# DHCP
-A INPUT -i "$INTIF" -p udp --dport 67 -j ACCEPT
# PLEX
-A INPUT -p tcp --dport 32400 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i "$INTIF" -p udp --dport 1900 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i "$INTIF" -p tcp --dport 3005 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i "$INTIF" -p udp --dport 5353 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i "$INTIF" -p tcp --dport 8324 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i "$INTIF" -p udp --dport 32410 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i "$INTIF" -p udp --dport 32412 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i "$INTIF" -p udp --dport 32413 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i "$INTIF" -p udp --dport 32414 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i "$INTIF" -p tcp --dport 32469 -j ACCEPT
# SSH
-A INPUT -i "$INTIF" -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
# TRANSMISSION
-A INPUT -p tcp --dport 59156 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i "$INTIF" -p tcp --dport 9091 -j ACCEPT
# HTTP(S)
-A INPUT -i "$INTIF" -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
# SAMBA
-A INPUT -i "$INTIF" -p tcp --dport 139 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i "$INTIF" -p tcp --dport 445 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i "$INTIF" -p udp --dport 137 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i "$INTIF" -p udp --dport 138 -j ACCEPT
# FACETIME & IMESSAGE
-A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p udp --dport 3478 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p udp --dport 3497 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp --dport 5223 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p udp --dport 16384 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p udp --dport 16387 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p udp --dport 16393 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p udp --dport 16402 -j ACCEPT
# ROUTING
-A FORWARD -i "$EXTIF" -o "$INTIF" -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i "$INTIF" -o "$EXTIF" -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -j LOG
COMMIT


/etc/openvpn/US-California.conf

client
dev tun
proto udp
remote us-california.privateinternetaccess.com 1194
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
ca ca.crt
tls-client
remote-cert-tls server
auth-user-pass login
comp-lzo
verb 1
reneg-sec 0
crl-verify crl.pem
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DNS resolution does not work because you forgot to add a proper /etc/resolv.conf to your network namespace. There are two peculiarities to this.

First, this is done *outside* the *iproute2* commands.

```
        mkdir -p /etc/netns/nns
        echo "nameserver 8.8.8.8" > /etc/netns/nns/resolv.conf
        echo "nameserver 8.8.4.4" >> /etc/netns/nns/resolv.conf
```

Change nns with the name of your network namespace.

Second, this needs to be done *before* you create the network namespace, in which case a brand new /etc/resolv.conf will appear in the namespace, which is totally unrelated to the hosts's, and which can be manipulated in exactly the same way as the host's, while leaving the host's copy unscathed.

You can easily add the above commands to the pre-up section of your br1 stanza in /etc/network/interfaces, and likewise for the commands that remove the file to the post-down section.

It is also easy to see why DNS does not work on your system: you are using Ubuntu which, for DNS, uses dnsmasq running on the `lo` interface, at address 127.0.1.1 (just look into /etc/resolv.conf) so that your DNS requests go to the lo interface, are intercepted by your instance of dnsmasq, which takes it upon itself to resolve DNS queries. Since you have not changed /etc/resolv.conf, you are still using that of the host, which refers to `lo`: but on `lo` in the network namespace `vpn` there is no instance of dnsmasq listening to DNS queries.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your /etc/openvpn/server.conf has `push "dhcp-option DNS"` pointing to the AirPort Extreme. Try updating that setting and check your VPN again.